# What do i need to return to tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, cgfloat

I have a view controller with several tables.  I want one table to have larger cells than the others.  Right now, I have:

```
- (CGFloat *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView != myBigTable)
    {
        return 44;
    }
    else
    {
        return 88;
    }
}
```

I get a warning saying

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a
>   function with result type 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *')

and when I run it, it crashes.

I've also tried:

- `return 44.0` - error for double to float* conversion
- `return 44.0f` - error for float to float* conversion
- `CGFloat *height; height = 44; return height;` - same errors as just returning the value I want directly

I've looked for something like `[CGFloat floatWithDouble:44.0];` as is done with an NSNumber, but I haven't found anything.  What am I supposed to be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function declaration is wrong. It must be

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The return type is `CGFloat` and not `CGFloat *`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

and remove the * after your return type.